# python multiprocessing - select-like on running processes to see which have one have finished

Tags: python, multiprocessing, waitpid

I want to run 15 commands but only run 3 at a time

testme.py

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import random
import subprocess

def popen_wrapper(i):
    p = subprocess.Popen( ['echo', 'hi'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    print stdout
    time.sleep(randomint(5,20)) #pretend it's doing some work
    return p.returncode

num_to_run = 15
max_parallel = 3

running = []
for i in range(num_to_run):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=popen_wrapper, args=(i,))
    running.append(p)
    p.start()

    if len(running) >= max_parallel:
        # blocking wait - join on whoever finishes first then continue
    else:
        # nonblocking wait- see if any processes is finished. If so, join the finished processes
```

Im not sure how to implement the comments on:

```
if len(running) >= max_parallel:
    # blocking wait - join on whoever finishes first then continue
else:
    # nonblocking wait- see if any processes is finished. If so, join the finished processes
```

I would NOT be able to do something like:

```
for p in running:
   p.join()
```

because the second process in running would have finished but im still blocked on the first one.

Quesion: how do you check to see if processes in `running` is finished in both blocking and nonblocking (find the first one finished)?

looking for something similiar to waitpid, maybe

Comment: Can you make a successfully finished process to send your watching process a message via a queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way to arrange this is to use a [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool):

```
pool =  mp.Pool(3)
```

will set up a pool with 3 worker processes. Then you can send 15 tasks to the pool:

```
for i in range(num_to_run):
    pool.apply_async(popen_wrapper, args=(i,), callback=log_result)
```

and all the machinery necessary to coordinate the 3 workers and 15 tasks is
taken care of by `mp.Pool`.

---

**Using mp.Pool**:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import random
import subprocess
import logging
logger = mp.log_to_stderr(logging.WARN)

def popen_wrapper(i):
    logger.warn('echo "hi"')
    return i

def log_result(retval):
    results.append(retval)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    num_to_run = 15
    max_parallel = 3
    results = []

    pool =  mp.Pool(max_parallel)
    for i in range(num_to_run):
        pool.apply_async(popen_wrapper, args=(i,), callback=log_result)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    logger.warn(results)
```

yields

```
[WARNING/PoolWorker-1] echo "hi"
[WARNING/PoolWorker-3] echo "hi"
[WARNING/PoolWorker-1] echo "hi"
[WARNING/PoolWorker-1] echo "hi"
[WARNING/PoolWorker-3] echo "hi"
[WARNING/PoolWorker-1] echo "hi"
[WARNING/PoolWorker-3] echo "hi"
[WARNING/PoolWorker-1] echo "hi"
[WARNING/PoolWorker-3] echo "hi"
[WARNING/PoolWorker-1] echo "hi"
[WARNING/PoolWorker-3] echo "hi"
[WARNING/PoolWorker-1] echo "hi"
[WARNING/PoolWorker-1] echo "hi"
[WARNING/PoolWorker-3] echo "hi"
[WARNING/PoolWorker-2] echo "hi"
[WARNING/MainProcess] [0, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 13, 1]
```

The logging statements show which PoolWorker handles each task, and the last logging statement shows the MainProcess has received the return values from the 15 calls to `popen_wrapper`.

---

If you'd like do it without a Pool, you could set up a `mp.Queue` for tasks and a `mp.Queue` for return values:

**Using `mp.Process` and `mp.Queue`s**:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import random
import subprocess
import logging
logger = mp.log_to_stderr(logging.WARN)

SENTINEL = None
def popen_wrapper(inqueue, outqueue):
    for i in iter(inqueue.get, SENTINEL):
        logger.warn('echo "hi"')
        outqueue.put(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    num_to_run = 15
    max_parallel = 3

    inqueue = mp.Queue()
    outqueue = mp.Queue()
    procs = [mp.Process(target=popen_wrapper, args=(inqueue, outqueue)) 
             for i in range(max_parallel)]

    for p in procs:
        p.start()
    for i in range(num_to_run):
        inqueue.put(i)
    for i in range(max_parallel):
        # Put sentinels in the queue to tell `popen_wrapper` to quit
        inqueue.put(SENTINEL)

    for p in procs:
        p.join()

    results = [outqueue.get() for i in range(num_to_run)]
    logger.warn(results)
```

---

Notice that if you use

```
procs = [mp.Process(target=popen_wrapper, args=(inqueue, outqueue)) 
         for i in range(max_parallel)]
```

then you enforce there being exactly `max_parallel` (e.g. 3) worker processes. You then send all 15 tasks to one Queue:

```
for i in range(num_to_run):
    inqueue.put(i)
```

and let the worker processes pull tasks out of the queue:

```
def popen_wrapper(inqueue, outqueue):
    for i in iter(inqueue.get, SENTINEL):
        logger.warn('echo "hi"')
        outqueue.put(i)
```

---

You may also find [Doug Hellman's multiprocessing tutorial](https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/index.html) of interest. Among the many instructive examples you'll find there is [an `ActivePool` recipe](https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html#controlling-concurrent-access-to-resources) which shows how to spawn 10 processes and yet limit them (using a `mp.Semaphore`) so that only 3 are active at any given time. While that may be instructive, it may not be the best solution in your situation since there doesn't appear to be a reason why you'd want to spawn more than 3 processes.